# HockeyApp iOS: разрешить установку на все устройства

Tags: ios, xcode, тестирование

Доброго времени суток. Имеется приложение написанное в XCODE которое необходимо регулярно тестировать на других устройствах. Ранее добавляли устройства в provision profile. Есть ли способ разрешить установку приложения на всех устройствах? Что бы новым тестерам не приходилось ждать пока добавят его устройство?

Comment: этот вопрос очень хорошо описывает СО: задаешь вопрос про hockeyapp, получаешь два ответа про testflight

Answer (score 1):

В https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ можно добавить пользователей как внешних тестеров. Тогда их не нужно будет добавлять в провижен.

Но есть небольшой минус, приложение не очень быстро на этом testflight обновляется. Можно до одного дня прождать

Answer (score 1):

В TestFlight можно сделать открытое бета тестирование, но для этого нужно каждый раз апрувить приложение (та же процедура, что и перед выкладыванием в стор). Других способов без добавления пользователей в provision profile не существует